# require js file wont execute

Tags: javascript

.js file won't execute

This is part of the code in my .js file I'm trying to execute with the node. I've tried switching it all about repeatedly but I can't get it to work.
    var buffer = "";
    var log = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the whole command in quotes. Since we don't know what `testone.js` is supposed to do, it's hard to know how it should be called.

Nevertheless, try something more like this:

```
require('child_process').exec('"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" testone.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    console.log(stdout)
});
```

Comment: That didn't seem to help at all. Here is the entire code block;

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with the full block of code. I added the if statement. didn't work, so I removed it.

Comment: So that looks right now. How will you know if  `testone.js` ran correctly? What is it supposed to do?